# Adding children to GridLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic, dimensions, grid-layout

I have an app that will display a grid of the same image, based on the dimensions chosen by the user. I'm using GridLayout to build that grid, but so far, I have been unable to figure out a way to set up the children (multiples of that image) in the java code so that the size of the grid and number of children will change with the settings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that should work for me. In the blog post announcing GridLayout, they posted [this code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/GridLayout0.html) that pretty easily shows how to add to the Grid.

Comment: Update link if possible, please